# Failure to send email java at the Azure project

Tags: java, email, azure, jakarta-mail

I have a problem I researched a lot, spent many hours and I can not solve it.

I have a java web application that at a certain time of the day sends alert emails to certain users. Local tests done and everything worked perfectly, but when I went up the application to the Azure, it does not send emails. I am using an email from Gmail to authenticate and sending emails.

I'm using Commons Email 1.4.

Since I enabled the Gmail option for sending low security with devices.

Segue o código para envio do e-mail:

```
public static String sendEmail(String to, String name, String subject, String body) {
        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
        try {
            email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
            email.setSmtpPort(465);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
            email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
            email.setFrom("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setMsg(body);
            email.addTo(to, name);
            email.send();

            return "sent";
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            return sw.toString(); 
        }
    }
```

Tracking error:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1401)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1428)
    at br.com.farofa.abf.email.Email.enviarEmailTeste(Email.java:101)
    at br.com.farofa.abf.webservice.restful.UsuarioResource.enviarEmailTeste(UsuarioResource.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1391)
    ... 42 more
```

I hope to help me. I do not know what to do.
Thank you!

Comment: Enable [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and post the debug output.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue. It was caused by Gmail security policy for allowing less secure apps. You can refer to the google accouts help https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en.

The solution is turn on access for less secure apps, see the picture below:

[image]

Click "Less secure apps" section https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps?hl=en and turn on it, see below.

[image]

However, if you want to send Email on Azure, I recommend to use SendGrid on Azure to do it, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-java-how-to-send-email/ to try it.